# how do I create an index column in HTML Table

Tags: angular, html-table

I need to create a serial column of objects obtained by the get method of an external API. But I can not create this column in the table.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
         <th scope="col">#</th>
         <th scope="col">Nome</th>
         <th scope="col">Sobrenome</th>
         <th scope="col">Participação</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr id="table-grid" *ngFor="let chart of charts">
            <th>{{chart.id}}</th>
            <td>{{chart.name}}</td>
            <td>{{chart.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{chart.participation}}%</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ChartGraph();
    this.Parallax();
  }
  getId() {

  }
  ChartGraph() {
    this.mainService.getChart().subscribe(data => this.charts = data)
```

JSON:

```
[{
    "name": "Carlos",
    "lastname": "Moura",
    "participation": 5.00
}, {
    "name": "Fernanda",
    "lastname": "Oliveira",
    "participation": 15.00
}, {
    "name": "Hugo",
    "lastname": "Silva",
    "participation": 20.00
}, {
    "name": "Eliza",
    "lastname": "Souza",
    "participation": 20.00
}, {
    "name": "Anderson",
    "lastname": "Santos",
    "participation": 40.00
}]
```

I need the table to look like this:
[image]

currently it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngFor` provides you an `index` of every iteration. You simply need to use the same as follows -

```
<tr id="table-grid" *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index">
    <th>{{(i + 1)}}</th>
```